# React-table - Force refresh os data using onFetch

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to use component react-table in my ReactJS project. I'm using external data source (server processing) and it's working. To get data, i'm using prop called `onFetchData`, which call's my function called `fetchData(state, instance)`. This is working fine. But what I need now is to force refresh os this data. Let me explain: data from my table is coming from state property called 'data'. Whe I change anything in react-table, react-table itself call function declared in 'onFetchData' and send his (table) internal state as parameter. This state has filters and sorting props.....this is fine.
When my '`fetchData(state, instance)`' execute, it call's my external script and get data, save this data to state and refresh my table. All this is working fine!
But now I have 3 external filters in my screen (not in react-table!) and when I change these filter, I would like to call '`fetchData(state, instance)`' again to force refresh os data......but I can't because I don't have current table 'state' (which contains current table filters and ordering).
I can call my '`fetchData(state, instance)`' when I change any filter on my screen, but I lose any filter set in mu react-table.

Comment: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/955

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/r5q81w4wwq